# Get Facebook Public Profile Picture

Tags: facebook, image, public

I am trying to obtain my client's photos without redirecting them to facebook to grant me access to the graph.  Is it possible to get their profile picture by email without having their user id?

I created a dev account and have an app, but it seems it doesn't work without an access token.

Comment: Can you post the code you've already written?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing their user_id, this is not possible. Once you know the user_id, you can query it via `/{user_id}/picture` without having to use an Access Token (see documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)